# Prepending data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask

I am making a site that will allow you to tweet other's messages. Each message will have its tweets in a csv file. I will loop through the csv file, finding all the tweets for the given message and arranging them into a list.

The thing is, when I loop throught the data, the oldest tweets (the ones at the very start of the file) would appear first in the list. Is there a way to either loop through the pandas DataFrame from bottom to top, or when appending the tweets append them to the very start of the file? Here is my code:

```py
current_message_name = 'Draft Message' # This is the name of the message the user is veiwing right now.

tweets = []
df = pd.read_csv('data/tweets.csv')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tweets.append({
    'poster':f'{row["poster"]}',
    'date':f'{row["date"]}',
    'message':f'{row["message"]}',
 })
```

Comment: `df.iloc[::-1]` will reverse the order of the rows.

Comment: `tweets.pop()` will get the last item in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres how you can approach it:

```
current_message_name = 'Draft Message'
tweets = []
df = pd.read_csv('data/tweets.csv')

# Reversing the DataFrame
df = df.iloc[::-1]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tweets.append({
        'poster':f'{row["poster"]}',
        'date':f'{row["date"]}',
        'message':f'{row["message"]}',
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Try not to loop in pandas. (ref: [Does pandas iterrows have performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues))

If you need a list of dictionary, use `to_dict`.

```
tweets = df.iloc[::-1][['poster', 'date', 'message']].to_dict(orient='records')
```